# How I can rowspan kendo grid ui

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want rowspan in gird kendo ui like this picture ?
[Images example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s85EJ.png)
Thanks so much!

Comment: See [column templates](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/excel/column-template-export). Post your grid code if you need assistance getting there.

Answer (score 0):

Row spanning implies one of the following:

- that you will have access to at least two data items for a single table row element in a column or a row template, during rendering. This, unfortunately, is not possible with the Kendo UI Grid.
- even if you manipulate the table structure in the Grid's `dataBound` event, the Grid will not be aware of this and some operations will not work correctly (e.g. editing, selection, data item retrieval, etc.)

As a result, row spanning is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

With me, use rowTemplate:

```
var index = 0;
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [{
    title: "Name + Age", 
    columns: [{title: "Name"}, {title: "Age"}]
  }],
  dataSource: [ 
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 }, 
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 }, 
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 }, 
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 }, 
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 }, 
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 } 
  ],
  rowTemplate: 
  '<tr> '+
    '#if(index++ % 3 == 0){# '+
        '<td rowspan=3><strong>#=name#</strong></td> '+
    '#}#   '+
    '<td><strong>#: age #</strong></td>'+
  '</tr>'
});
</script>
```