# Row span in kendo grid UI

Tags: kendo-grid

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWuv6.png): 
Is there any way to merge cell by using kendo UI grid as shown in given picture.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo does not support row span.

Did you see the suggestion on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51202131/4944034? This seems to do the trick.

There are some more suggestions on https://www.telerik.com/forums/rowspan-for-grouped-rows#AP6q-rZssEetfVoMbNfqRw

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any Kendo functionality to implement this. So the simple solution is to use Client Template

```
    function CrmClientTemplate(firstValue,secondValue) {
    
    return "<table class='crmTbl'>" +
        "<tr><td class='crmTblTd1'>" + firstValue + "</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td class='crmTblTd2'>" + secondValue+"</td></tr>" +
        "</table>";
    }
```

Grid change

```
 columns.Bound(p => p.JanLbs)
.Title("Jan Lbs.")
.Width("4%")
.ClientTemplate("#= CrmClientTemplate(data.FrirstValue,data.SecondValue) #");
```

If you want to add cell border, use the CSS (Optional)

```
 .crmTblTd1 {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(213, 213, 213);
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .crmTblTd1 {
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(213, 213, 213);
        padding-top: 5px;
    }
```